# Finding the path between 2 nodes in a graph in scheme

Tags: scheme, depth-first-search

can someone please explain why i have the error:

```
 map: contract violation
  expected: list?
  given: 'e3
  argument position: 2nd
  other arguments...:
   #<procedure>
```

in the code below???

My expected output is: '(e4 e5 e0)

I'm trying to use the depth first search algorithm to find the path between 2 nodes, the code is:

```
#lang racket


(define successors    ; finding successor of a node in graph
  (lambda (node graph)
    (let ((val (assq node graph)))
      (if val
          (cdr val)
          '()))))

(define make-task cons)
(define task-node car)
(define task-path cdr)
(define same-node? eq?)

(define linked    ; function to find the path between 2 nodes in a graph

    (lambda (start end graph)   ; begin, end: nodes    graph: a graph                         

      (define handle-node                                
        (lambda (node path todo seen)
          (if (same-node? node end)
              (reverse (cons node path))
              (if (assq node path)
                  (process-todo todo seen)
                  (process-todo (append (map (lambda (successor)
                                                  (make-task successor
                                                             (cons node
                                                                   path)))
                                                (successors node
                                                            graph))
                                           todo)
                                (cons node seen))))))

      (define process-todo
        (lambda (todo seen)
          (if (null? todo)
              #f
              (let ((task (car todo)))
                (handle-node (task-node task)   ;;; node
                             (task-path task)   ;;; path
                             ((lambda (x y) (cdr y)) task todo) ;;; rest to do
                             seen)))))

      (handle-node  start '() '() '())))

(linked 'e4 'e0 '((e1 . e0) (e2 . e1) (e3 . e2) (e4 . e3) (e4 . e5) (e5 . e0)))
```

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your `successor` function has a 'type' error.  The alternate of the `if` returns a list (actually `'()`) whereas the consequent of the `if` returns `(cdr val)` which is not a list (based on your input data).  This is confirmed from the error message - a `list?` was expected but a `symbol?` was provided.

It looks like your graph representation is meant to be an association between the node name and a **list of the connected node names**.  But your input data is not in that form!  Try:

```
'((e1 e0) (e2 e1) ...)
```

By the way, `successor` is written idiomatically as:

```
(define (successor node graph)
  (cond ((assq node graph) => cdr)
        (else '())))
```